# "set_UVC" equivilent for a 3D quiver plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

To update a regular 2D quiver plot you can use `.set_UVC()` to directly set the `x` and `y` data.

The 3D equivalent to the quiver is the `Axes3D.quiver()`, this however does not seem to have an equivalent to `.set_UVC()`. How can the data updated? The `segments` does seem to contain the data from the quiver arrows however I don't see how the input data and the segments correlates.

I can delete the quiver plot then re-plot a new one however that is inefficient and would impact the performance, I want know if there is a way to set the data directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a look at the `Line3DCollection` code, you'll see that not too many methods from the `LineCollection` class have been overloaded. For you the important one is `set_segments()`, which looks like this:

```
def set_segments(self, segments):
    '''                                                                                                                
    Set 3D segments                                                                                                    
    '''
    self._segments3d = np.asanyarray(segments)
    LineCollection.set_segments(self, [])
```

So when `set_segments()` is called, the segments are actually stored in `self._segments3d` and the `LineCollection`'s `set_segments()` method is called with an empty list. `Line3DCollection` then takes care of its own segments list in an overloaded `draw()` method. Two things to notice:

1. Even if you follow the matplotlib example and use `numpy.meshgrids` to define your quiver coordinates, within `_segments3d` the coordinates are stored in an array of shape `(N,2,3)`, where N is the amount of points and its content is basically `[[[x0,y0,z0],[u0,v0,w0]],[[x1,y1,z1],[u1,v1,w1]],...]`, so you probably have to manipulate your data to fit that format.
2. Apparently you cannot assign the new values directly to `_segments3d`. At least for me that resulted in the figure not updating properly -- you have to go through `set_segments()`. However, you can *access* the previous values by reading out `_segments3d`, if you, for instance, just want to alter some of the coordinates.

Here still some arbitrary example which I produced to test all the things I just explained:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

num_frames = 50
theta = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi, 10, endpoint=False)
r = np.arange(1,2.1)
z = np.arange(-2,2.1,1)


def compute_segs(i):
    offset = 2*i*np.pi/num_frames
    theta2,r2, z2 = np.meshgrid(theta+offset,r,z)

    x = r2*np.cos(theta2)
    y = r2*np.sin(theta2)

    u = x+0.2*np.cos(4*theta2)
    v = y
    w = z2+0.2*np.sign(z2)*np.sin(4*theta2)

    return x,y,z2,u,v,w


segs = compute_segs(0)
cols = ['b' for x in segs[0].ravel()]
cols[0] = 'r'
quivers = ax.quiver(*segs, length=0.1, colors = cols, normalize=True)


ax.set_xlim([-3,3])
ax.set_ylim([-3,3])
ax.set_zlim([-3,3])
def animate(i):

    segs = np.array(compute_segs(i)).reshape(6,-1)

    new_segs = [[[x,y,z],[u,v,w]] for x,y,z,u,v,w in zip(*segs.tolist())]
    quivers.set_segments(new_segs)
    return quivers


ani = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames = num_frames, interval = 30, blit=False)
ani.save('update_3d_quiver.gif', writer='imagemagick')

plt.show()
```

...and the result looks like this:

[image: result of the above code]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I just realised that my example is only half correct -- I will post an edit in a while.

Comment: Great solution. The only problem is that you don't get arrows from the quiver function like this, just straight lines. I am trying to find a way to still maintan the arrow shape.

Comment: Now I realized what is the issue - the array of shape (N,2,3) is not actually [x0,y0,z0], [u0,v0,w0]... and so on. Each pair of 3 coordinates is actually a single line. The first pair defines the arrow body and the two next pairs define the lines of the arrow head. so its actually [[x0+u0,y0+v0,z0+w0], [x0,y0,z0]], then [[x0+u0,y0+v0,z0+w0],[a,b,c]] (first arrow head line), then [[x0+u0,y0+v0,z0+w0],[d,e,f]] (second arrow head line). Each three arrays in the main array are a single arrow.

Answer (score 5):

To elaborate on Thomas Kühn's answer that I have accepted, if you have your grid points and the data for the quivers that you want to convert to segments you can use the following function.

```
def quiver_data_to_segments(X, Y, Z, u, v, w, length=1):
    segments = (X, Y, Z, X+v*length, Y+u*length, Z+w*length)
    segments = np.array(segments).reshape(6,-1)
    return [[[x, y, z], [u, v, w]] for x, y, z, u, v, w in zip(*list(segments))]
```

You can then update the segments of your plot using the output, this way also allows you to use the length to specify the normalisation length of the arrows, it is usually best to set this to a multiple of the mean or maximum of the input data (`np.sqrt(vv**2 + uu**2 + ww**2)`).

```
segments = quiver_data_to_segments(X, Y, Z, uu, vv, ww, length=5)
quiver_plot.set_segments(segments)
```